# Ajax-jquery alerting an 404

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty

I am using Jquery to make some ajax request :

```
$('#my-btn').click(function() {ldelim}
    var comment = $('#textarea').val();
    var m = {$id};
    var data = {ldelim}
          comment: $('#textarea').val(),
          m: {$id}
        {rdelim};

        $.post('index.php?page=page',data,function(callback_data){ldelim}

        var content = $('div.my-btn').html();
        $('div .comments').append(content);
                ...
        alert(callback_data);
{rdelim});
{rdelim});
```

(The reason of that {rdelim} or {$id} is that I am using the template engine Smarty.)

The processing of my php code works just fine : the bdd is correctly implemented but the alert of the callback sends an '404', preventing me from echoing a data number from my php code. (When I call for an echo($data) in my php code, I get the alert of $data+404).

Does anyone has an idea ?

Best,
Newben

Comment: i have the same number response. One way to get rid of 404 is to make some callback_data=(callback_data-404)/1000; but it is really not acceptable

Answer (score 1):

The callback for jQuery's `.post()` is only for success (HTTP status code 2XX) responses. To have a callback for 404's you need to use `.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?page=page',
    data: data,
    success: function(callback_data) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Please see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ vs. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: After re-reading your question, I realize that I don't understand the question at all, so this may not help you. Can you show the PHP code, or explain a bit more?

Comment: Apparently your PHP code is echoing a 404. The "bug" is probably in your PHP and not in the JavaScript. My answer assumed that the 404 was an HTTP status code, which would be sent with PHP `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");`

Comment: In fact, my php code stores the posted comment in the database, and then I want to retrieve the id of the comment ($c_id), so I make an echo($c_id), to call it from the callback ajax

Comment: Please use Firebug to look at the server's response to the POST request. Please tell me exactly what the body of the response contains.